# Repetitive autoincrement between spaces

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know how to write a number under a cell with text, then write that same number until it finds another text, then increment it and do the same over and over. Keep in mind that we dont know how many spaces will it be between each text.

Here is a image of what I mean, its very clear here:

[image: Image example]

I am no expert on excel just used it a few times and know the basics but I really need this formula to avoid hours and hours of work doing this manually. You would help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), you need a separate column and this formula:

`=IF(E1="",COUNTA(E1:$E$1),E1)`

The trick is in the range, which is always starting with `E1`, because of the two `$-signs`, but ending with the pulled row. Then simply pull down column `F`, it will increment:

[image]

Comment: clever solution!

Comment: Oh man, thank you really much! That was exactly what I was looking for.